# When WP_CLI runs Wordpress from the command line, are hooks called?

Tags: hooks, wp-cli

Yesterday, I found out that a website I worked on as a writer (I have no admin access) had been injecting malicious Javascript code in all its pages, as described in [this article by Luke Leal](https://lukeleal.com/research/posts/trainresistor-cc-mass-injection/).

According to that article, a **fake Wordpress plugin** musts have been installed on that website to inject the malicious code.

I want to draw your attention to this section of the malicious code:

```
// This code is defined inside a PHP class...
function save_striplple_plugin() {
    global $wp_list_table;
   $h = array('wp-striplple/wp-striplple.php');
    $myplugins = $wp_list_table->items;
    foreach ($myplugins as $key => $val) {
        if (in_array($key,$h)) {
        unset($wp_list_table->items[$key]);
        }
   }
    
}

public function striplple_start(){
    ...
    add_action('pre_current_active_plugins', [$this, 'save_striplple_plugin']);
}
```

The second method adds the first method to the `pre_current_active_plugins` hook. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_current_active_plugins/), that hook runs before creating a list of the **installed plugins**; not the active plugins, the installed plugins.

The first method runs when that action is called and **deletes the fake plugin from the list of installed plugins**.

So, **I wondered how we could create a list of the installed plugins on a website that could not be manipulated by an attacker**. A first way, from the top of my head, is to **access the website** through the **FTP** and see what's in the `/plugins` folder.

Then **I wondered if WP_CLI would show us this fake Wordpress plugin in the list of plugins**. Although I've used WP_CLI before, I don't think I really understand its inner processes and how it interacts with a Wordpress installation.

**When WP_CLI runs Wordpress from the command line, are hooks called? Would a list of plugins generated with WP_CLI be manipulated by this fake Wordpress plugin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WP CLI will run plugins by default, so any hooks used in active plugins would be run.

You can tell WP CLI to *not* run the active plugins, though. To get the full list of plugins, even if a malicious plugin tries to hide itself, the following *should* work:

`wp plugin list --skip-plugins`

(Caveat: any must-use plugins will still be loaded. To disable MU plugins, you'd need to remove them from the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory.)

`--skip-plugins` is a [global parameter](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/references/config/#global-parameters), so you should be able to use it on any `wp *` command. `--skip-themes` is also available.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I tested the malicious code in a local website, it hid the plugin from the Wordpress plugin list, but it didn't hide it from the WP-CLI command `wp plugin list`, even without the `--skip-plugins` parameter.